# Multiple input-ouput and steps winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a winform application where a set of classes and its methods calculate a geometry from 3d points.

As there is some input from the user needed from step to step in the algorithm we have designed some buttons which represent the steps. The intermediate data is stored in a class (maybe we use a structure in future Versions), so as the user input is. As result of pushing the Buttons the intermediate data will be calculated, saved and shown to the user, so that he can edit it, affecting to the calculation in the next steps.

The application began as an application which calculate everything in 4 steps but now we have more than 10 steps so we have divided it into 3 parts (horizontal geometry, vertical geometry and other...). Now I am doing some divisions because everything is getting too complex to manage all the gui interaction in one Form so I will create user controls for the smaller parts of the form.

Do you have general recommendations for me?

Should I have these data structures (input and intermediate data) in the controls I make or in the general form?

Comment: "maybe we use a structure in future versions" - why are you considering that at all? You should get a better understanding of .NET before making such design choices.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid mixing UI with the business logic. In that way when the program grows larger it will be a lot easier to maintain. It will also make it much simpler to write automated unittests.

If there is no particular reason you are using winforms. I would recommend using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). Read a tutorial about the Model View ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern. This is a very nice way of separating the UI logic from the business logic.

It takes some effort to switch from Winforms to WPF but it is definitely worth it.

**EDIT (answer to comment)**

Well it depends on the problem your solving. But generally:

In the MVVM pattern the:

Model would contain all your data and algorithms in classes/methods. The ViewModel would connect all the stuff you have in your Model and control the flow of the program, it will expose properties (commands, strings, numbers collections etc...) that view can bind to. The View is simply a "skin" that makes it possible for the user to communicate with the ViewModel. This is a very simple explanation of the MVVM pattern and I would recommend reading a tutorial about it.

The first time I came across this pattern it was called Model View Controller MVC, I like what AngularJS is doing by just calling it Model View Whatever MVW because there are a lot of MV* out there. But WPF is specifically built for MVVM.

The most important thing, if your creating a program that is going to be used and maintained for many years, is to keep the code as simple as possible. Instead of writing all the functionality into the Button_Click event handler (I have seen some programs that do this), try to write a class or method for every single task (use long descriptive names), this is also called Seperation of Concerns. In other words one method/class should not do more than one tasks. The nice thing is that you end up with a "program flow controller" (ViewModel/Whatever) that just passes data from one method to the next. And just by looking at the code you go: Aha I know exactly what is going on here! In the same way when you look at your algorithms (Model) they should do a single job and all variables should be have descriptive names. This makes it very easy for other developer to understand the code.

I also have very good experience with dividing my namespaces according to type. So every time you have more than one object of some sort (DataProviders, FileReaders, etc...) create a namespace/subnamespace for them and put them in there. So when your creating a new object/interface/enumeration... you always know where to put it. And you always know where to find again: Oh its a DataProvider so it must be located in ProjectName.Objects.DataProviders :)

So my recommendation is: have some fun and read about: MVVM and SoC

Comment: Yes. That's what I try. I have the data and the algorithms (steps and "substeps") in a VS Project and the GUI in a separate one (which depends on the first).

I decided to use Windows Forms because I had experience with it and because there are some components made with Windows Forms (I know we can mix them but I wanted to avoid mixing technologies) I could use... maybe a wrong decision but now I have no time to change it.

If I use WPF, where are the data structure declared and contained? Are they contained in the Form or in some other container?

Answer (score 0):

Probably  [state machine diagram](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_statediagram.html) will help you do devide actions in parts. It's a better practice, to create some of diagrams before codding.